# Array of structs in shared memory for two processes

Tags: c, arrays, struct, parent-child, shared-memory

I'm trying to create an array of structs to share between a parent and child process using "shmget". I am following a template from my professor, but his did not include structs and arrays (the shared memory only stored an int). The following code compiles without warnings but returns " 0" as the output, I am expecting to see "a 10". What am I doing wrong?

Also I am having trouble when i try to declare new variables inside the child processes, I have seen other samples where it works but I don't know why I am being forced to declare them before the fork everytime.

```
typedef struct { 
    char character;
    int number;
} item;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int mem_id;

    mem_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 10*sizeof(item), SHM_R | SHM_W);
    item * x;
    item * y;
    item * list[10];

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
            perror("Bad fork()"); exit(1);
        case 0:
            *list = shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
            if ((int *) list == (int *) -1)
            {perror("Child cannot attach"); exit(1);}           

            x->character = 'a';
            x->number = 10;

            list[0] = x;

            shmdt(list);
            exit(0);
        default:
            *list = shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
            if ((int *) list == (int *) -1)
            {perror("Child cannot attach"); exit(1);}

            wait((int *)0);
            y = list[0];
            shmdt(list);

            printf("%c %d\n", y->character, y->number);

            if (shmctl(mem_id, IPC_RMID, 0) <0)
                { perror("cannot remove shared memory"); exit(1);}

            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you never initialize `x`

Comment: If you just need to share between parent and child, don't bother with the ugliness of `shmat` etc. Just use `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED` before the `fork`, and the mapped region will be shared between parent and child. Best of all you don't have to worry about cleaning it up when you exit.

Comment: All of your `item`s are pointers. You also never initialize them, which means you are changing data at an unknown location.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that you didn't segfault since:

1. You don't initialize x as Nemo pointed out
2. Your array "list" is actually an array of pointers to Items instead of being an array of Items.
3. Most importantly.  You detach shared memory before you print out the value in y.

The code should look like this:

```
typedef struct { 
    char character;
    int number;
} item;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int mem_id;

    mem_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 10*sizeof(item), SHM_R | SHM_W);
    item *x;
    item *y;
    item *list;

    switch(fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("Bad fork()"); exit(1);
    case 0:
        list = (item *)shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
        if ((void *) -1 == (void *)list)
        {
            perror("Child cannot attach"); exit(1);
        }
        x = list;
        x->character = 'a';
        x->number = 10;

        shmdt(list); // No need for this
        exit(0);
    default:
        list = (item *)shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
        if ((void *) list == (void *) -1)
        {
           perror("Child cannot attach"); exit(1);
        }

        wait((int *)0);
        y = list;
        printf("%c %d\n", y->character, y->number);

        shmdt(list);

        if (shmctl(mem_id, IPC_RMID, 0) <0)
            { perror("cannot remove shared memory"); exit(1);}

        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you iterate over array here?